How to Copy-Paste "0" if Cell is Blank
I am compiling a template from multiple spreadsheets into one spreadsheet. I am putting all of the templates onto one sheet with one column in-between each table. Some of the data has blank values and I want the code to replace this blank value with a 0. Because the macro I've written only copy-pastes integers, it does not return a blank value and so the templates are blending together.
This is the code I have written so far and am trying to include a statement saying if the range has any blank cells, replace the blank with a zero in the new spreadsheet.
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim FileNameXls, f
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, I As Integer

    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each f In FileNameXls
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    
    For I = 1 To 1
    
        wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:H20").Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    
    Next I
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
Next f
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


Maybe looping through the cells after you have copied them and inserting a 0 in the empty ones?


Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value is more efficient than copy/pastevalues.

Using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) to get the blank cell(s) in destination range.

Please always qualify all Range objects with the sheet object to avoid errors. eg. Sht2.Cells(7, Sht2.Columns.Count).


Option Explicit
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim FileNameXls, f
    Dim wb As Workbook, I As Integer
    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copyRng As Range, Sht2 As Worksheet, blankRng As Range
    For Each f In FileNameXls
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
        For I = 1 To 1
            ' define source range
            Set copyRng = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:H20")
            Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
            With Sht2.Cells(7, Sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).Resize(copyRng.Rows.Count, copyRng.Columns.Count)
                ' get values of the source range
                .Value = copyRng.Value
                Set blankRng = Nothing
                ' get blank cell(s) in destination range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set blankRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not blankRng Is Nothing Then
                    ' fill blank cells
                    blankRng.Value = 0
                End If
            End With
        Next I
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next f
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

